# Tasks in snowflake - multiple SQLs

Tags: sql, task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can a Task execute multiple SQLs at a time in single transaction? I know stored procedure does but wanted to see if we can start a transaction in task and execute multiple SQLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A task can execute one SQL statement or a stored procedure.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/tasks-intro.html

So: You have to create a stored procedure with all your statements and call that procedure within the task.